# How do I display floats as currency with negative sign before currency

Tags: python, pandas

consider the `pd.Series` `s`

```
s = pd.Series([-1.23, 4.56])
s

0   -1.23
1    4.56
dtype: float64
```

I can format floats with pandas `display.float_format` option

```
with pd.option_context('display.float_format', '${:,.2f}'.format):
    print s

0   $-1.23
1    $4.56
dtype: float64
```

But how do I format it in such a way that I get the `-` sign in front of the `$`

```
0   -$1.23
1    $4.56
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can substitute the formatting function with your own. Below is just a demo of how it works, you can tune it to your own needs:

```
def formatfunc(*args, **kwargs):
    value = args[0]
    if value >= 0:
        return '${:,.2f}'.format(value)
    else:
        return '-${:,.2f}'.format(abs(value))

with pd.option_context('display.float_format', formatfunc):
    print(s)
```

And you get:

```
0   -$1.23
1    $4.56
dtype: float64
```